# Load a different ViewController with UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a UISearchBar and when the user clicked on the search button in the keyboard I want to load the results in another ViewController that I have, but when I press the Search button nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
#import "BuscadorViewController.h"
#import "EventosViewController.h"

@interface BuscadorViewController ()<UISearchBarDelegate>

@end

@implementation BuscadorViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate Methods

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    [self loadViewResults];
}

#pragma mark - Methods
-(void)loadViewResults
{
    NSString *title = self.searchBar.text;
    EventosViewController *evc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"listaEventosID"];
    evc.parametro = title;
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:evc animated:YES completion:nil];
    // [self.navigationController pushViewController:evc animated:YES];
}
```

- The keyboard hides perfectly.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't see any where that you set Delegate..?

Comment: Yes, I set the delegate in the StoryBoard and also put that line in viewDidLoad but nothing happens. Thanks you.

Comment: you have to put breakpoint at "loadviewresults' and make sure that evc controller not be nil..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see any where that you set Delegate..You have to set delegate for that like this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
}
```

and also Use below code surely this will work..Make sure that you have to set view controller relationship in your storyboard.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"listaEventosID"]) {
            NSString *title = self.searchBar.text;
                evc.parametro = title;
    }
}

-(void)loadViewResults
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"listaEventosID" sender:nil];
}
```

Comment: it works !! I have to make a relationship from BuscadorViewController to EventosViewController in StoryBoard.